# Change format in datetime2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to change the format of a `datetime2` variable `'2019-07-08 14:30:20'` to `20190708`.

I tried this in my query:

```
...
where
id_date = CONVERT('2019-07-08 14:30:20', 112);
```

But it returns incorrect syntax error.

Comment: `CONVERT('2019-07-08 14:30:20', 112); `, you're missing the datatype you want to convert to

Comment: `'2019-07-08 14:30:20'` isn't a variable, it's a literal. If you want `'20190708'` then write `'20190708'`.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your information. I know exactly what it is. I gave an example of how the 'literals' are stored in the columns.

Comment: *" I know exactly what it is"* Then why state *"I want to change the format of a `datetime2` **variable** `'2019-07-08 14:30:20'`"* in your question? It's *not* a variable. If, however, it *was* a variable then just make the data type of the variable a `date`, and it has no time section. Either way the question ends up being moot; either you have a literal and shouldn't be typing the time or you should be using a `date` variable and thus is has no time portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast first to `datetime2` and then convert to `varchar`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CAST('2019-07-08 14:30:20' as datetime2), 112);
```

That returns

`20190708`

As you expect.

Answer (score 2):

First, `date`/`time` values are stored using *internal* formats.  So, you cannot set the format.

So, if you just want to remove the time component, you can use:

```
set id_date = convert(date, id_date)
```

If you want the column as a string YYYYMMDD, then you can add a computed column:

```
alter table t add id_date_str as (convert(varchar(8, id_date, 112));
```